# Export data from highcharts in csv file with dates in milliseconds

Tags: angularjs, csv, highcharts, export-to-csv

I have an angularjs application with the library Highcharts.

In my application I have some graphs and want to export the data of the graphs in a CSV file. So I used the exporting function from highcharts but I have a problem with the dates. On my graphs, I display the dates with a format "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss" so when I export my data, I have the same format but I would have the dates in milliseconds. I try to change teh 'dateFormat' field in the exporting options but milliseconds is not part of the accepted formats.

This is my graph options:

```
widgetCtrl.chartDataLine = {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x',
        isZoomed: false,
        marginTop:55
    },
    title: {
        text: 'title',
        align:'left',
        x: 20,
        y: 18,
        style: {
            fontSize: '14px'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: 'Date time'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Power (W)'
        }
    },
    boost: {
        enabled: true
    },
    exporting: {
        fallbackToExportServer: false,
        enabled: true,
        allowHTML: true,
        filename: 'myFile',
        menuItemDefinitions: {
            downloadJSON: {
                onclick: function () {
                    downloadJSON('myFile.JSON', widgetCtrl.chartDataLine.series);
                },
                text: 'Download JSON'
            }
        },
        csv: {
            decimalPoint: '.',
            dateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: [
                    'printChart',
                    'downloadPNG',
                    'downloadJPEG',
                    'downloadPDF',
                    'downloadSVG',
                    'downloadCSV',
                    'downloadJSON'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            align: 'left'
        }
    }
    series: [...]
};
```

Do you have an idea how I coul do that without writing myself teh csv file but using the highcharts functions ?

Comment: Would need to `map()` the series and parse and convert date strings using `Date`  API before passing to `downloadJSON()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Highcharts does not have the default option to export data in milliseconds (timestamp). However, it can be done easily by [wrapping](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) `Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getDataRows` method and map the data array which is used for export.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getDataRows', function(proceed, multiLevelHeaders) {
    var rows = proceed.call(this, multiLevelHeaders);

    rows = rows.map(row => {
      if (row.x) {
        row[0] = row.x;
      }
      return row;
    });

    return rows;
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5p1nvq37/